# Design of a person buying at a store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to model the steps to a store from a persons standpoint and need help with the model design and how to actually implement the "bought this product/service" part.

So far I think the model design would be:

```
Person
  has_many :purchases

Purchase
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :product

Products
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :purchases
```

A Person can purchase many products as they want.

I want to make the "bought this product" ability a checkbox that would then assign a `Purchase` to the product but how is done? Is my model design correct?

Comment: So someone can only purchase a single product or service at a time?

Comment: @Beerlington They can have many so they select the products that they bought just like if you were to go to a store in real life.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the model should be closer to this.

```
Service:  
belongs_to :store  
has_many :products  

Products:  
belongs_to :store  
has_many : purchases
```

The reasoning behind this is that a `Service` should generate a `Product` whether that is a tangible good in the real world is not important (I think).  For instance a mechanic provides the `Service` of auto repair and the end `Product` is a repaired vehicle.

**UPDATE**

Essentially what needs to happen is your `Person` would just need a `Collection` or `List` (I don't know the ruby data type, but it is a standard data structure) that would be of type `Product`.  When displayed on the UI, you would simply iterate over all `Products` in that `Person` and those would be everything they own.  Now if you mean everything the `Person` owns intersected with the total inventory that is a slightly different question.  The approach is the same, except you simply take the intersection of the two lists of products (the ones the Person owns and the one one in total inventory) and you get everything that the Person owns.

Comment: Right now I'm just going to get rid of the whole service thing. I don't think its needed. I changed up my question to reflect this. Would this be the correct model design? What about the "bought this product" ability?

Comment: @Railslearner updated my response let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could make this a bit simpler using `through`, and if you don't actually need Purchase to be a model, you could just do a HABTM (Person `has_and_belongs_to_many` Products).

```
Person
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :products, :through => :purchases

Purchase
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :product

Product
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :buyers, :through => :purchases, :class => 'Person'
```

When a Person buys a product, you can record this:

```
@person.products << Product.find(100)
```

The relevant Purchase will automatically be built and saved. If you want to record additional information, such as the price of the Product at the time of the Purchase, you can create `before_save` callbacks that set those values in the Purchase model:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  before_save :record_price

  def record_price
    self.price = product.price
  end
end
```